# overflow x not working even though width and height are specified react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am making a react app and this is my css for the apiresults component.

```css
.Api {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    hsl(204, 76%, 70%) 0px,
    hsl(204, 76%, 70%) 105px,
    hsl(249, 76%, 70%) 105px,
    hsl(249, 76%, 70%) 210px,
    hsl(294, 76%, 70%) 210px,
    hsl(294, 76%, 70%) 315px,
    hsl(339, 76%, 70%) 315px,
    hsl(339, 76%, 70%) 420px,
    hsl(24, 76%, 70%) 420px,
    hsl(24, 76%, 70%) 525px,
    hsl(69, 76%, 70%) 525px,
    hsl(69, 76%, 70%) 630px,
    hsl(114, 76%, 70%) 630px,
    hsl(114, 76%, 70%) 735px,
    hsl(159, 76%, 70%) 735px,
    hsl(159, 76%, 70%) 840px
  );
  color: white;
  h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
  overflow-x: hidden;
  .flex-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    img {
      max-width: 100vw;
      padding: 20px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    .flex-grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      img {
        max-width: 50vw;
      }
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .flex-grid {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      img {
        max-width: 33vw;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that overflow x is not working even though i specified width and height. All the answers I found said

> specify the width and height
> however i did already and i still see the side scroll bar

Comment: please include the html

Comment: When `overflow-x: hidden;`, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @UdanHiwarale it doesnt hide it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. I am not sure if you are trying to make your component scroll horizontally or vertically. In order to make a component scroll whichever way you want, you will have to add a

`width` and/or `height` to the container holding the components, then add
`overflow-x: auto` if you want it to scroll horizontally; and
`overflow-y: auto` if you want it to scroll vertically;

As you said you're seeing the side scroll-bar, you need to add `overflow-y: hidden` in order to stop seeing it.

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for more information on how overflow works